# what is =~ in following script

Tags: bash, shell

this script check that a directory is a parent of another. how to work this script?

```
     T() {
          if [[ "$2" =~ ${1}['/'?] ]] ; then
              echo "$2 is child of $1"
              return 0
          else
              echo "$2 is NOT child of $1 ($?)"
              return 1
          fi
         }
```

Comment: Read the [`bash` manual page](http://linux.die.net/man/1/bash).

Comment: Your question is phrased ambiguously. Do you want to know how this script is working - in particular what the `~=` is doing, or how to use this script? Please clarify it.

Comment: To avoid confusion about what's going on here, [we took the liberty to do some experiments with this questions](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/192242/you-made-too-few-changes-to-the-post-to-improve-it).

Comment: @Bobby - please can you can stop now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From manual:

```
An additional binary operator, ‘=~’, is available, with the same precedence as ‘==’ and ‘!=’. When 
it is used, the string to the right of the operator is considered an extended regular expression 
and matched accordingly (as in regex3)). The return value is 0 if the string matches the pattern, 
and 1 otherwise.
```

Answer (score 2):

It's a regular expression match, a helpful tool to match a string to a pattern.
[This link](http://linux.die.net/Bash-Beginners-Guide/chap_04.html) may help you.

Answer (score 2):

It is a regular expression pattern match operator.  See the `bash` reference manual under [Conditional constructs](http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bash.html#Conditional-Constructs) — and look for the `[[ ... ]]` construct.